# Stop swagger changing the type for example values

Tags: java, swagger, springfox

Let's say you have a model property like this.

```
@ApiModelProperty(notes = "Post code", example = "50676")
private String postCode;
```

Swagger sees that the example is all numeric and automatically changes this to numeric in the generated docs, despite the actual type being String.

e.g.

```
    "postCode": {
      "type": "string",
      "example": 50676,
      "description": "Post code"
    },
```

The swagger version is managed via Maven as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

The project is based on spring boot 2.2.2.RELEASE.

Is there a way to force the type to be String in the example? It should really match the field type.
Thanks

Comment: @ravinikam good question, I added the relevant details now

Comment: There are apparently a couple of workarounds. If the example has a leading zero then it stays as a string. Also the example can be entered like "'50676'". I find it a bit ironic that a framework devoted to documentation doesn't document it's own functions fully.

Comment: yeah, thats what I also found out, like we need to put quote's inside quotes. You may be want to create defect against SpringFox as I think swagger just puts as is whatever you give in the quotes.